# cout no output but printf does

Tags: c++, assembly, printf, cout

I'm very new to programming in C++ but I'm trying to write some code which filters a specific word from a string and then takes a specific action. For some reason the code does not see the text inside the string.

```
printf("%s \n", data.c_str());
cout << data;
```

This shows absolutely nothing - meaning I cannot use `.find` or write it to a file.

```
printf("%s \n", data);
```

This shows exactly what I need.

I am writing the code into data with assembly:

```
mov data, EDX
```

Why is that I can only use the the last method?

Edit:
Data is initiated as:
    `std::string data;`

Comment: what's the type of data? show how you initialize it.

Comment: If `printf("%s \n", data);` works... something's wrong if data is a string.

Comment: Maybe I should be using wchar_t instead? Because the input comes via assembly from another program.

Comment: You still haven't answered any of my questions... what is the type of `data` and how are you initializing it (just saying `mov data, EDX` is not nearly enough... I'm very inclined to downvote the question. If you want help, you need to provide more info.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Im sorry. The data is coming via a 'codecave', I hooked into another program which sends the data first to my dll before it proceeds. Data is initiated as std::string data;

Answer (score 4):

If a pointer to a string is null all subsequent calls to cout
stop working

```
 const char* s=0;
 cout << "shown on cout\n";
 cout << "not shown" << s << "not shown either\n";
 cout << "by bye cout, not shown\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The two function calls are not equivalent, as `\n` at `printf` flushes the stream. Try with:

```
cout << data << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. unfortunately it seems like it only clears the console screen.

Comment: @user1477410: Is what I assume is a `std::string` _data_ empty by any chance?

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand what you are meaning.

Comment: @user1477410: Is `data` an `std::string`? I assume it is but wouldn't know for sure as you haven't showed us its declaration. In case it is a `std::string`, is it empty? As in `data.empty()` returns `true`.

Comment: Yes, data is a std::string and it is empty. Only the assembly codes adds a value to it.

Comment: @user1477410: You can't modify the contents of a `std::string` via _assembly_, you don't know its internals and even if you did all you'd get would be _Undefined Behavior_, which is probably what you are seeing already.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you used

```
#include <string>
```

in your file header. With this in place you should be able to use

```
std::cout << data << endl;
```

with no issues. If you're using a global namespace for std you may not need the std::, but I'd put it anyway to help you debug a it faster and eliminate that as a possible problem.

Answer (score 0):

### In Short

You will have a problem with **cout**, if you don't put a **linebreak at it's end**!

### In Detail

Try adding an `endl` to your `cout` (e.g. `std::cout << data << std::endl`), or use following instruction to activate "immediate output" for cout (without it needing a linebreak first).

```
std::cout << std::unitbuf;
```

Complete example:

```
std::cout << std::unitbuf;
std::cout << data; 

// ... a lot of code later ...
std::cout << "it still works";
```

Sidenote: this has to do with output buffering, as the name `unitbuf` suggests (if you want to look up what is really happening here).

This way it is also possible to rewrite the current line, which is a good example, where you would need this ;-)

### Practical example

```
using namespace std;

cout << "I'm about to calculate some great stuff!" << endl;
cout << unitbuf;

for (int x=0; x<=100; x++)
{
    cout << "\r" << x << " percent finished!";

    // Calculate great stuff here
    // ...

    sleep(100);  // or just pretend, and rest a little ;-)
}
cout << endl << "Finished calculating awesome stuff!" << endl;
```

Remarks:

- \r (carriage return) puts the curser to the first position of the line (without linebreaking)
- If you write shorter text in a previously written line, make sure you overwrite it with space chars at the end

Output somewhere in the process:

```
I'm about to calculate some great stuff!
45 percent finished!
```

.. and some time later:

```
I'm about to calculate some great stuff!
100 percent finished!
Finished calculating awesome stuff!
```